# Spring, Java : Passing Generic object List as return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, casting

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which depending upon the mode set by the user, I have to return a List of either Object1 or Object2. Ideally, I can create two controller methods and send the List appropriately, but I would like to know is there any way, I can send any type of List in that Controller method.

Controller method :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/findnotebydays/{days}/{canvasid}/{mode}")
public @ResponseBody List<Inotes> findNotesByDays(@PathVariable("days")int days, @PathVariable("canvasid")int canvasid,
                                                  @PathVariable("mode")boolean mode ){

    if(!mode){
        return this.groupNotesService.findGroupNotesByDays(days,canvasid);
    } else {
        return this.notesService.findNotesByDays(days,canvasid);
    }
}
```

Basically, if mode is false, I want to return `List<GroupNotes>` and if mode is true, I would like to return `List<Notes>`. My naive approach that I thought I can just say it is an Object and return, but doesn't seem to work. Kindly let me know what I can do. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Update*

GroupNotes model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupnotes")
public class GroupNotes implements Inotes{

  @Id
    @Column(name="mnoteid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "mnote_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mnote_gen",sequenceName = "mnote_seq")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "mnoticesidindex")
    private int mnoticesid;

    @Column(name = "mnotetext")
    private String mnotetext;
//Other variables, getters, setters ignored
}
```

Notes model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="note")
public class Notes implements Inotes{

    @Id
    @Column(name="noteid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "note_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "note_gen",sequenceName = "note_seq")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "noteidindex")
    private int noticesid;

    @Column(name = "notetext")
    private String notetext;
//Other variables, getters, setters ignored
}
```

Interface Inotes :

```
package com.journaldev.spring.model;


public interface Inotes {
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error as return type expected is Inotes, and passed it GroupNotes or Notes.#

Comment: exactly, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a common interface shared by both classes.

Declaring an interface like, for instance:

```
public interface INotes{

}

public class GroupNotes implements INotes{...}

public class Notes implements INotes{...}
```

Your code would become:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/findnotebydays/{days}/{canvasid}/{mode}")
public @ResponseBody List<INotes> findNotesByDays(@PathVariable("days")int days, @PathVariable("canvasid")int canvasid,
                                                  @PathVariable("mode")boolean mode ){

    if(!mode){
        return  this.groupNotesService.findGroupNotesByDays(days,canvasid);
    } else {
        return this.notesService.findNotesByDays(days,canvasid);
    }
}
```

Another simpler solution would be just returning `List` (or `List<?>` for compliance) but this approach is more appropriated.

Comment: I just did what you said, I am pasting the model class, check it out in 2 mins.

Comment: At the return line, it says, Required return type List<Inotes>, got List<GroupNotes> or List<Notes> for 2nd return.

Comment: Try the other approach, returning List<?>, though is not the best practice

Comment: Well, that worked. Thanks. :-) Can you please elaborate why it is not a best practice in this situation?

Comment: Because a method should be self-defined, which means you should always try to specify what that method gets and returns in the best way. List<?> returns a list of anything, which doesn't give any information of what you can get unless you read the code. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Any ways the guy in front end does not care which object type it is. This should work just fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Following the clean coder style, if you have to pass a boolean to a method, that method actually does two different things, and you want a method to do only one thing.

I would just make two controller actions, it is much clearer to the user and to the maintainer of the code later on.

Comment: The method does the same thing, just retrieves information from different tables.

Comment: Retrieving from two tables are two different things.

Comment: I agree, but this is not some major thing which I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `Notes` and `GroupNotes` are both implementing the Note interface (for example), you could always return `List<Note>`.

Comment: No, both of them don't implement a common interface, they are separate. Should I post the model class for both?

Comment: That would help a lot.

Comment: Added. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Considering both the `findGroupNotesByDays` and `findNotesByDays`  methods return instances of the supertype `Inotes`, changing your return type to `List<Inotes>` should do the trick.

Comment: Even I thought the same, but it still gives me error, I updated Controller code in main post too.

Comment: What do the `findGroupNotesByDays` and `findNotesByDays` methods return?

Comment: They return List<GroupNotes> and List<Notes> respectively, should I change that in service and DAO as well? If yes, then I have to go down till DAO method and query.list should also return Inotes.